# Printing out a list of coordinates of a grid given x y dimensions

Tags: function, haskell, coordinates

I need to put out a list of coordinates of a grid given the width and height x y. I originally tried something like this

```
allCoords :: Int -> Int -> [GridCoord]
allCoords x y 
| x <= 0 || y <= 0 = error "allCoords: Grid dimensions must have positive Integers"
| 0 <- x, 0 <- y = [(0,0)]
| 0 <- x = grid 0 y 
| otherwise = grid x y ++ allCoords (x-1) y 
where 
   grid :: Int -> Int -> [GridCoord]
   grid x 0 = [(x,0)]
   grid x y = (x,y):grid x (y-1)
```

This did give me an output of

```
allCoords 3 2
[(3,2),(3,1),(3,0),(2,2),(2,1),(2,0),(1,2),(1,1),(1,0),(0,2),(0,1),(0,0)]
```

However the expected output is

```
[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,1)].
```

I had thought maybe using List comprehension by creating two functions that put all x elements into a list and y elements into a list and then doing a Cartesian product but thought this was a bit of a stuff around.

I realised now that x will increase while y remains the same and once we reach the mmax of x we increase y. This requires me to hold a variable to hold the max value of x and y because we need to comparre current x to them. I am so lost now on how to even start and I'm more so looking for hints rather than have the code written out so I can learn. I know I need a case of x but should I use foldl? an accumulator? and what would that look like as accumulators still confuse me

EDIT** 
I've tried with List Comprehension but I'm not sure how to combine.

```
allCoords :: Int -> Int -> [GridCoord]
allCoords x y 
| x<= 0 || y <=0 = error "allCoords: Grid dimensions must have positive Integers"
| otherwise = lst1 ++ lst2
where 
 lst1 x = [(x,0) | x <- [0..x-1]]
 lst2 y = [(0,y) | y <- [0..y-1]]
```

But It threw an error for Lst2. Can I combine like this? I also tried to have the two lst's in separate functions and that throws errors with the type declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is very close.

The error you're getting is because `lst1` and `lst2` expect an argument, but you're not passing any arguments to them in `lst1 ++ lst2`. As `x` and `y` are already known, you could just remove them in `lst1` and `lst2` like this:

```hs
allCoords :: Int -> Int -> [GridCoord]
allCoords x y 
    | x<= 0 || y <=0 = error "allCoords: Grid dimensions must have positive Integers"
    | otherwise = lst1 ++ lst2
  where 
         lst1 = [(x,0) | x <- [0..x-1]]
         lst2 = [(0,y) | y <- [0..y-1]]
```

However, this function now gives you `[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(0,0),(0,1)]`, so either `x` or `y` is always `0`. To combine  the values, you can just generate the tuples in a single line of list comprehension.

```hs
allCoords :: Int -> Int -> [GridCoord]
allCoords x y 
    | x<= 0 || y <=0 = error "allCoords: Grid dimensions must have positive Integers"
    | otherwise = [(x,y) | y <- [0..y-1], x <- [0..x-1]]
```